# Sticky door when opening, sounds like sticky paint

Tags: doors, paint, noise, door-frame, noise-reduction

I am trying to find a solution to my door sticking when I open it. It creates a loud popping sound from the wood after being stuck together. This would be my bathroom door, i work late hours and when I come home, the door makes the sound and wakes the dogs, wife and baby... not very fun! Anyway, im sure the paint is latex or something and I was thinking of putting some Vaseline on it to keep it from sticking, but the problem with that is... correct me if im wrong, but it causes dust build up and becomes sticky itself... I also have some lube for my pool rings, the stuff you put on your pool filter lids to keep them from getting stuck... only I think those get sticky after a while too... and they smell. My final thought was to use WD-40, but that isn't really a lubricant... its just a water dispersal agent (hence the "WD"). I didin't want to do anything without some suggestions from the amazing people of diy! please help me. I live in Arizona... humidity is not really a problem (well except during monsoon season, but that is pretty mute since it lasts for a few months).